# EditorFor extension not working for htmlAttributes in Asp.Net MVC 5.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5.1, editorfor

I have the following code:

```
public static class HtmlExtendedHelpers
{

    public static IHtmlString eSecretaryEditorFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel,TProperty>> ex, object htmlAttributes, bool disabled )
    {

        if (disabled)
        {
            htmlAttributes.Add(new { @disabled = "disabled" }); //searching for working code as replacement for this line
        }

        return htmlHelper.EditorFor(ex, htmlAttributes);

    }
}
```

It works when disabled = false and all my alternatives fail when i disabled is true. Then none of the htmlAttributes are getten written.

The variable htmlAttribute has the VALUE ( including htmlAttributes property :)

```
htmlAttributes: { class = "form-control" }
```

This is because i have a default class of form-control and i want to add a attribute : disabled with value disabled.

Does anyone know how to implement this correctly?

PS. Since Asp.Net MVC 5.1, there is support for htmlAttributes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes`

```
var attributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);

if (disabled)
{
    attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

Alternatively, you could pass the `disabled` attribute as part of the `htmlAttributes` object, meaning you wouldn't need the `if` statement at all.

```
htmlAttributes: { class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled" }
```

Depending on whether you have a custom `EditorFor` template or not, you may need to change how you pass the html attributes to the `EditorFor` function, as the parameter it accepts - `additionalViewData` is not the same.

[This article](http://cpratt.co/html-editorfor-and-htmlattributes/) explains in more detail.

If you are using a default template, you can pass the html attributes inside another anonymous object:

```
return htmlHelper.EditorFor(ex, new { htmlAttributes = attributes });
```

If you have a custom template, you will need to retrieve the html attributes and apply them yourself in the view:

```
@{
    var htmlAttributes = ViewData["htmlAttributes"] ?? new { };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the attributes in the htmlAttributes like below:

```
htmlAttributes: { class = "form-control", disbaled="disabled" }
```

Also you can create your Metadata Attribute which can be decorated on your property for which you are using EditorFor.

To create your own Metadata Property you can implement `IMetadataAware` interface.